# App::import not working for controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need to load controller class and I try:

```
App::import('Controller','AppController');
```

or

```
App::import('Controller','PagesController');
```

But this every time returns false. When I try this:

```
App::import('Model','AppModel');
```

it returns true, so it seems it's not working for controllers - why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `App::import(type, name)` for a controller, you don't need to include "Controller" in the name you import, just when creating the instance variable.

```
App::import('Controller', 'Pages');
$Pages = new PagesController;
```

Comment: But he should still use App::uses - since he uses 2.x!

Comment: I agree with mark here, `App::uses('Pages', 'Controller');` is more appropriate for 2.x

Comment: No, I need App::import - I just need to load class but not construct it.